# Initializing in swift

Tags: swift, initialization

How do I initialize the following code?

```
import Foundation

class RecordedAudio: NSObject{
    var filePathUrl: NSURL!
    var title: String!
}
```

Comment: With an `init` method?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var myVariable = RecordedAudio()
```

Though, given that `filePathUrl` and `title` are implicitly unwrapped optionals (which I'd have to recommend against), you might want to create a better initialization method:

```
init(filePathUrl: NSURL, title: String) {
    self.filePathUrl = filePathUrl
    self.title = title
}
```

And then use that initialization.

```
var myVariable = RecordedAudio(filePathUrl: someUrlVar, title: someStringVar)
```

Comment: After changing the code, I was told that there s a missing argument for paramater filePathUrl. 
Where should I put var myVariable = RecordedAudio()

Answer (score 0):

In your Recorded Audio Class, add the initialization code:

```
class RecordedAudio: NSObject{
    var filePathUrl: NSURL!
    var title: String!

    init(filePathUrl: NSURL, title: String) {
        self.filePathUrl = filePathUrl
        self.title = title
    }
}
```

Then, in your audioRecorderDidFinishRecording method, in the ViewController you are doing the recording in, replace the commented out code with the live code like this:

```
    func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder!, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if(flag){
            // Save the recorded audio
            // prior to adding initialization:
//            recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()
//            recordedAudio.filePathUrl = recorder.url
//            recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent

            // Using initialization
            recordedAudio = RecordedAudio(filePathUrl: recorder.url, title: recorder.url.lastPathComponent!)

            // move to next UI
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("stopRecording", sender: recordedAudio)

        } else {
            // If recording not successful
            recordingUIEnabled()
        }
    }
```